# How to make zero-mean random noise with standard deviation equal to 1?

Tags: matlab

Hi Now I'm trying to make a equation within MATLAB.

the equation which is zero-mean random noise with standard deviation equal to 1

How to make zero-mean random noise with standard deviation equal to 1 ?

.

Comment: Type `help randn` on the command line ...

Comment: @BasSwinckels If you can would you please let me know what is this mean? also the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [randn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html). It will create a vector or matrix with 0 mean and one variance, normally distributed.

```
noise = randn(nrows,ncols);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, Does randn function include 0 mean itself ? How can I set the number of mean? for example, I want to set 2mean or 3..4..5. how can I make?

Comment: Yes it does: https://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/randn.html . Check this website for worked out examples